# jq add value of a key in nested array and given to a new key

Tags: json, bash, addition, jq, ndjson

I have a stream of JSON arrays like this

```
[{"id":"AQ","Count":0}]
[{"id":"AR","Count":1},{"id":"AR","Count":3},{"id":"AR","Count":13},
{"id":"AR","Count":12},{"id":"AR","Count":5}]
[{"id":"AS","Count":0}]
```

I want to use jq to get a new json like this

```
{"id":"AQ","Count":0}
{"id":"AR","Count":34}
{"id":"AS","Count":0}
```

34=1+3+13+12+5 which are in the second array.
I don't know how to describe it in detail. But the basic idea is shown in my example. 
I use bash and prefer to use jq to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're just adding all the counts by IDs?

Comment: yes...............!!!!

Comment: It'd be easier if your desired output were `{"AQ": 0, "AR": 34, "AS": 0}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the .id is the same in each array:

```
first + {Count: map(.Count) | add}
```

Or perhaps more intelligibly:

```
(map(.Count) | add) as $sum | first | .Count = $sum
```

Or more declaratively:

```
{ id: (first|.id), Count: (map(.Count) | add) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an efficient but generic solution that does NOT assume each input array has the same ids, then the following helper function makes a solution easy:

```
# Input: a JSON object representing the subtotals
# Output: the object augmented with additional subtotals
def adder(stream; id; filter):
  reduce stream as $s (.; .[$s|id] += ($s|filter));
```

Assuming your jq has `inputs`, then the most efficient approach is to use it (but remember to use the -n command-line option):

```
reduce inputs as $row ({}; adder($row[]; .id; .Count) )
```

This produces:

```
{"AQ":0,"AR":34,"AS":0}
```

From here, it's easy to get the answer you want, e.g. using `to_entries[] | {(.key): .value}`

If your jq does not have `inputs` and if you don't want to upgrade, then use the -s option (instead of -n) and replace `inputs` by `.[]`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit kludgey, but given your input:

```
jq -c '
  reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[($item.id)] += ($item.Count))
  | to_entries
  | .[] | {"id": .key, "Count": .value}
'
```

Yields the output:

```
{"id":"AQ","Count":0}
{"id":"AR","Count":34}
{"id":"AS","Count":0}
```

Comment: you know that jq has a function add right? I was thinking if I could use jq 'map(.Count) | add' which returns 0 34 0 and then give these 3 number a key "Count". But I don't to know how to add value to a new key....

Comment: I would try your method first!